# how can I validate data in yii2 manually?

Tags: yii2-validation

I wrote a function that creates a 6-digits number.

how can I validate this number manually without using models in yii2?

Comment: is there some code you could add to your question? that could be helpfull

Comment: got it! I should use "ad-hoc validation" or "inline validation" .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think it's useful:

```
<?php
  public function actionValidation(){
    $model = new \yii\base\DynamicModel(['number']);
    $model->addRule('number', 'integer', ['message'=>'should be a number']);
    $model->number = $this->yourFunction();
    Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_JSON;
    return ActiveForm::validate($model);
 }

  public function yourFunction(){
    return 6-digits-number;
 }
?>
```